# Where to download rails.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I believe that rails.js is required for `:remote => true` to work on rails forms, but I don't have rails.js in my public/javascripts folder. I have:

```
application.js
jquery.js
jquery.min.js
jquery-ui.js
jquery-ui.min.js
jquery-ujs.js
jrails.js
```

How do I get rails.js? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

### rails.js

> https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/tree/master/src

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/tree/master/src